# Проблемы с кодировкой файла при выводе файла, подгруженного AJAX'ом в IE и Edge

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

**Я решил уже эту задачу, ответ смотрите ниже, в ответах.**

На сайте есть подгрузка определенного файла через AJAX:

```
function showcont()  
            {  
                $.ajax({  
                    url: "<?bloginfo('template_url');?>/load_messes.php",  
                    cache: false,  
                    success: function(html){  
                        $("#result_div_id").html(html); 
                        $i++;
                    }  
                });  
            }
```

Все браузеры подгружаемый код отображают правильно кроме (как ни странно) браузеров от Майкрософт - то есть Edge и IE. Подгружаемый файл в UTF8. Что делать-то мне?)

Comment: что за ошибка?..

Comment: @Jean-Claude, просто неправильно выводит кириллицу

Comment: Воспользуйтесь сайтом определения кодировки https://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/ .

Comment: Какой заголовок content-type возвращается скриптом load_messes.php?

Answer (score 1):

Я, наконец-то, сделал то, что хотел))) - Помогла одна строчка в файле .htaccess -

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Эта строчка указала, что кодировка сайта по умолчанию - utf8, без нее Денвер указывал кодировку сайта windows-1251 (очень странно). Большинство браузеров не смотрели на эту строчку, а брали кодировку файла, то сеть utf8, а браузеры от Майкрософт брали не кодировку отдельного файла, а кодировку сайта в целом, то есть windows-1251, из-за этого и была несостыковочка))

Answer (score -2):

а метатэг указан? Я с помощью jquery.load() спокойно ставлю содержимое файлов на страницу (файлы в UTF-8). Хром и Эксплореры работают нормально

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

Ну или я бы попробовал в случае success метод append(), а не html()

Comment: указан, я уже решил эту задачу))